# Row-sums of the left inverse of a matrix with non-constant row-sums

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $P$ be a $n\times m$ matrix with linearly independent columns. Then $P$ has a left inverse $P^{-1}$. Let the vector of row-sums of $P$ be given by$$P\boldsymbol{1}_{m}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\sum_{j=1}^{m}P_{1j}\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{j=1}^{m}P_{nj}
\end{array}\right]$$ and assume that all row-sums are strictly positive. Is that true that the vector of row-sums of $P^{-1}$ is given by the following?$$P^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}_{n}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{m}P_{1j}}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{m}P_{mj}}
\end{array}\right].$$Note that this is trivially true if $P$ has constant row-sums $P\boldsymbol{1}_{m}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
k\\
\vdots\\
k
\end{array}\right]$ since in this case$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{k}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{k}
\end{array}\right]=\frac{1}{k}P^{-1}P\boldsymbol{1}_{m}=\frac{1}{k}P^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
k\\
\vdots\\
k
\end{array}\right]=P^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}_{n}.$$Hence I'm specifically interested in the case in which the row-sums of $P$ are not necessarily constant. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't write your desired formula if some of the row sums are $0$...

Comment: Ok then assume all row-sums are strictly positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true. As an example, take the matrix
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
It has row sums given by $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$; its inverse is
$$P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$
with row sums given by $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.